# Specifying filetype when using counsel-git-grep

Tags: ivy, counsel

I'm using `counsel-git-grep` to search inside a project for a specific string, which works great. However, I would like to additionally specify a filetype pattern to reduce the result set. I tried queries like `string -- '*.filetype'` but none of them worked. I know I can customize the `counsel-git-grep-cmd-default` but this seems to be a very static approach.

So the question is, is there a way to define a filetype pattern inside a query string of `counsel-git-grep`?

Comment: FWIW, a slightly less static alternative to customising `counsel-git-grep` is invoking `M-x counsel-git-grep-switch-cmd RET` to do it for you (with history).

Comment: You can also modify the command for each invocation of `counsel-git-grep` by calling it with a prefix argument, i.e. `C-u M-x counsel-git-grep RET`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement and have found this question on the internet search.

Because I didn't want to modify the git command every timeI wrote a small wrapper which adapts the git grep command to the current file extension:

```lisp
(defun counsel-git-grep-current-mode ()
  "Like `counsel-git-grep', but limit to current file extension."
  (interactive)
  (pcase-let ((`(_ . ,cmd) (counsel--git-grep-cmd-and-proj nil))
          (ext (file-name-extension (buffer-file-name))))
    (counsel-git-grep nil nil (format "%s -- '*.%s'" cmd (shell-quote-argument ext)))))
```

Source: [counsel-git-grep-current-mode](https://github.com/juergenhoetzel/counsel-git-grep-current-mode)